# Problems with UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a url defined as:

```
url(r'expand/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', ExpandData.as_view(), name='expand'),
```

Which is based on an `UpdateView`:

```
class ExpandData(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Reverse for 'expand' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app/expand/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

This happens when loading the application at the root url. I have no calls to `reverse('expand')` in my code.

Why is this happening. What is the workaround?

Comment: The full error message should give an indication of where the error is coming from. Perhaps you have `{% url 'expand' %}` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

So, my bad. I had this in one of my templates:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'app:expand' %}">{% trans "Expand" %}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll also need to mention `pk` as `kwargs` in `reverse()`

Something like this:

`reverse('expand', kwargs={'pk': 123})`